# Where Should References to Swagger be Removed in .Net 5 to Allow testing of APIs in localhost

Tags: .net

I am trying to run my Web API in Visual 2019 which has .Net 5 installed. I would like to see data on my test page when running Web APIs in localhost but right now when I run my APIs Swagger always shows up. I have seen videos and posts where the authors said references to Swagger can be removed from the ConfigureServices and Configure methods in the startup file.

I have tried what they suggested but I still see SWAGGER show up when testing my APIs in localhost. I cannot navigate to the test web page in localhost to test the APIs; every time I try I get an error. The following are what I have done to remove Swagger but it still shows up.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddTransient<TemplateServices>();
        //services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        //{
        //    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Editor", Version = "v1" });
        //});
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseSwagger();
            //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Editor v1"));
        }enter code here
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: It might be cached. Try it in an incognito/private window

Comment: I have tried running the web API in private window but I still see Swagger. I think it might have something to do with the launchSetting.json file. I'm not exctly sure what but I'll have to keep on messing with the settings in that file.